# Change Value of one cell only if Index number is known using powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0

I have a CSV file which holds telephone numbers. Based on the usage of the numbers, the status of the numbers will be either SPARE or USED.

Whenever I need to find the next SPARE number that can be used, I want to run the powershell Script which finds next SPARE number and assign this to new user (to be implemented later) and change the value of that particular number to USED.

I have managed to find the SPARE number using the script below but now once the number is found, I want to change the status of that number to USED.

```
$LineUri = @()
$Status = @()

$csv = Import-Csv C:\Users\user\Desktop\PhoneData.csv -Delimiter "," |`
    ForEach-Object {
        $LineUri += $_.LineUri
        $Status += $_.Status
    }

$currentStatus = "Spare"

if ($Status -contains $currentStatus)
    {    
    $Where = [array]::IndexOf($Status, $currentStatus)
    $AvailableURI = $LineUri[$Where]

    Write-Host "Next Uri Available: " $LineUri[$Where]

    $changeWhere = [array]::IndexOf($LineUri, $AvailableURI)
    }
```

My CSV file looks like below:

```
Name            LineUri Status
Test 1          3445660 Used
Test 2          3445663 Used
Test 3          3445664 Spare
Test 4          3445665 Used
Test 5          3445666 Spare
```

Once I run the above script, it returns the "3445664" as spare number.

Now I use this number, I want to change the Status of the number (3445664) to Used.

Once updated the CSV will look like below.

```
    Name            LineUri Status
    Test 1          3445660 Used
    Test 2          3445663 Used
    Test 3          3445664 Used
    Test 4          3445665 Used
    Test 5          3445666 Spare
```

Can someone with good powershell knowledge help me?

Comment: To be clear, do you want to specify a number, and if that number is found update the status to `Used`, or do you want to change the first occurrence of `Spare` to `Used`?

Comment: @arco444 First occurrence from spare to used.  $Where = [array]::IndexOf($Status, $currentStatus) , will give me the index of the location of the first occurrence.

Comment: My point is, you don't need to get the index to change the first occurrence, you just need to break out of the foreach loop when you find it. See the update in my answer

Comment: @arco444 What if I want to use index to change the status?

Comment: I don't know _why_ you would want to do that, but if you do, it's more efficient then to increment a counter until you hit the occurrence, still break out of the loop and subsequently use the counter value as the index

Comment: @acro444, thanks for you help, could you please implement your solution using my code snippet, I am not able to make this work at all..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will the first occurrence of `Spare` status to `Used`:

```
$csv = Import-Csv .\PhoneData.csv
$csv | % { if ( $_.status -eq 'Spare' ) { $_.status -eq 'Used' ; break } }
$csv | Export-Csv -Path .\PhoneDataNew.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

If you *really* want to use the index:

```
$i = 0
$csv = Import-Csv .\PhoneData.csv
$csv | % { if ($_.status -eq 'Spare') { break } ; $i+=1 }
echo $i
> 2 

$csv[$i]
> Name   LineUri Status
> ----   ------- ------
> Test 3 3445664 Spare

$csv[$i].Status = 'Used'
$csv | Export-Csv -Path .\PhoneDataNew.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I want to update the value of the cell which is store in $Where variable only. CSV will have other cells with the value Spare.

Comment: Can you update the question? It's not totally clear - do you want to update the last occurrence of `Spare`? Or the first one?

Comment: what I am trying to do is to find the SPARE number in the CSV and used it and then changed the value to used. I just want to update only one cell, not all the cells.

Comment: It's probably easier if you add a before and after example, I don't understand what you mean. Why does the line number matter? How do you know which `Spare` to update if there are many lines with that value?

Comment: I have re-phrased the question.

Answer (score 1):

The line `$csv = Import-Csv C:\Users\user\Desktop\PhoneData.csv -Delimiter ","` already gives you a nice object of the CSV file. No need to first put it in objects.

The code beneith will read the CSV, then looks at each line and when the Status is Spare, you can change to that line whatever you want to change. The last line of code exports the csv to the original file, where the `-force` parameters ensures it will be overwritten.

```
$file = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\PhoneData.csv"
$csv = Import-Csv $file -Delimiter ","
foreach ($line in $CSV) {
    if ($line.Status -eq "Spare") {
        $line.Status = "Something else"
        $line.Name = "Something else"
        $line.LineUri = "Something else"
    }
}
$csv | Export-Csv $file -Delimiter "," -NoTypeInformation -Force
```